# Canceling Networkconnection using UNC Path

Tags: c#, windows, networking, connection

I'm trying to disconnect network connections which are not mapped to a local drive (e.g. net use \server\share).

I know the command net use U: /D to delete a network connection which is mapped to U:.

Now I want to disconnect that connection using it's UNC Path (e.g. net use \server\ /D).

I want to implement this in a C# Application using the Windows Networking API (WNetCancelConnection-Function) but this function can't handle the UNC Path, too.

I receive all connected UNC Paths with the following code:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkConnection");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(queryObj["RemoteName"]);
            Console.WriteLine(queryObj["RemotePath"]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Hope so can help me solving that problem.

Edit:

```
i = WNetCancelConnection2A(ls_ShareName, iFlags, 1);
```

ls_ShareName = "\\server\share" (escaped)
iFlags = 0

results in: This network connection does not exist.

I'm 100% sure that my "shareName" is correct... also net use \server\share /D does not work.

Comment: [WNetCancelConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately Ive already tryed using wnetcancelconnection2 with an unc path - > exceprion, network does not exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where can be your problem without seeing your code. But after

```
net use \\192.168.1.45\ipc$
```

the following code

```
#include "windows.h"

void main(void){
    WNetCancelConnection2("\\\\192.168.1.45\\ipc$",0,TRUE);
}
```

disconnects the resource without problems.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed some informations. Now I've edited the question.

Comment: @Chill-X, Maybe you need to escape the backslashes

Comment: Thanks again but they're escaped, just forgot to mention that :/

Comment: The problem isn't solved yet but I've tryed these commands @home and there they're working, at work they're not - I don't get it